# Animation in 4.4.3 KITKAT is not working properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I am using a lot of animation on a particular fragment. I am using flip animation, frame animation using javascript on webview and rotating animation. Al these stuffs were working fine on nexus 5 when it was on 4.4.2 but after updating to 4.4.3, animation suffers. sometimes rotationg icon shows unpredictable behaviour like it flicked, sometimes flip animating images looks like breaked mirror. I am not getting the point why it is happening. Is it 4.4.3 issue or i need to change code at my side.

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Thanks

Ankur Chaudhary

Comment: you need to change code at your side.

Comment: @pskink can you please elaborate ? I didn't get your point as so far what i notice that flip animation is causing problem and for flip animation i use object animator like [link](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html)
 this example. So what i need to change now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FlipAnimation causing issue in 4.4.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272044/flipanimation-causing-issue-in-4-4-3)

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to a rendering problem in 4.4.3, as detailed in this issue:

[Rendering glitch on View since Android 4.4.3](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70914)

We saw this in an layout with a WebView (for ads) and a rotate animation. Use layer type of the WebView to View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE to work around the problem.It helps for me.

Thanks