# FlipAnimation causing issue in 4.4.3

Tags: android, animation, webview, android-animation

I am facing an issue regarding flip animation in 4.4.3 KITKAT in nexus 5. It was good when OS was 4.4.2 but after updating my nexus to 4.4.3 animation suffers.I am using flip animation over a layout which contains a webview and a rotating icon. So far after doing R&D i found that webview is causing the issue. If i load the url to webview , either flip animation suffers or rotating icon suffer but if i don't load the url to webview all animation is working properly.

Here i am sharing my sample code,

[link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/ouphj2h2u691753/TestAnimation.zip)

Please check and see the issue.

[image]

As you can see image when we start flip animation, background of layout that is slight transparent is break like mirror you can see the patches around webview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be related to a rendering problem in 4.4.3, as detailed in this issue:

[Rendering glitch on View since Android 4.4.3](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70914)

We saw this in an layout with a `WebView` (for ads) and a rotate animation. Try setting the layer type of the WebView to `View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE` to work around the problem.

Comment: Thank You so much .It works for me. You make my day. Can you elaborate why we need ti use all these stuff , while we were good in 4.4.2