# Actionbar issue because of webview in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-webview, navigation-drawer, android-5.0-lollipop

I have WebView in the page and sometimes when i open this activity i am having this issue in action bar which is shown in below image. Its not only on actionbar but sometimes on half screen.
[image]

Then if i click on navigation bar icon then it becomes alright. I have no idea why this is happening. I tested on android lollipop OS 5.0.2. But it had no issue when i downloaded my app in 5.1 and other OS lower than 5. I am not sure whether its because of OS 5.0.2 it is having this problem.

So anybody have come across this issue and explain me why this is happening.

Let me rephrase it, If i open any activity which has `WebView` container and the screen becomes like that shown in the image.

Comment: I have the same problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237090/system-ui-statusbar-and-navigation-bar-render-artifact

It seems to be a hardware flag assigned to the webview

Comment: Does this only happen on a specific device ?

Comment: Not device specific but OS specific. Like i found only in OS 5.0.2.

Comment: Thanks Hugo Gresse, that quick fix solved my problem.